# Problem in testing normal form

Tags: normalization

In the question given in the link https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/database-normalization-6/problem the answer is 2.

But I cannot understand why all the relations are not in BCNF (Since for all non-trivial functional dependencies of the form `X->Y`, `X` is a superkey of the corresponding relation). Someone please explain where I am wrong.

The question copied from hackerrank site:

> Let us take the example of a simple movie library. Each movie has a
>   description, director, and serial number. Customers have a name,
>   address, and membership number. Assume only one copy of each movie
>   exists in the library. We are given the following relations and
>   determinants. The keys for each relation are CAPITALIZED.
>
> ```
> Relations (The key is CAPITALIZED):
> customer(name,addr,MEMBERNO)
> movie(DESCRIPTION,director,serialno)
> borrow(memberno,DATE,SERIALNO)
>
> Determinants:
> description->director,serialno
> serialno->description
> serialno->director
> name,addr -> memberno
> memberno -> name,addr
> serialno,date -> memberno
> ```
>
> The above relation is in **x**NF form where x may take the following
>   values `{1,2,3,3.5}` corresponding to `{1NF, 2NF, 3NF and BCNF}` respectively.
>   What is the maximum possible value of **x** such that the
>   above relation satisfies the **x**NF form?

Comment: why not post your question in the [discussions forum](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/database-normalization-6/forum) associated with that question?

Comment: Please add all the necessary parts in the question so anyone who wants to answer doesn't have to read external links

Comment: You are correct. All the relations are in BCNF. But please, next time post the question as text and not as link.

Comment: @Renzo question updated. You can answer know (and I agree, the relations seem to be all in BCNF)

Answer (score 2):

**Problems in the exercise**

*Inconsistency*

In the exercise, it is said:

> We are given the following **relations** ...
>
> ```
> Relations (The key is CAPITALIZED):
> customer(name,addr,MEMBERNO)
> movie(DESCRIPTION,director,serialno)
> borrow(memberno,DATE,SERIALNO)
> ```

Then, a few lines later:

> The above **relation** is ...
>   ...
>   What is the maximum possible value of x such that the above **relation** satisfies the xNF form?

The three relations first presented become now a single relation, and I am not sure that this is a simple typo (see below).

*Terminology*

In the exercise, the term “determinant” is wrongly used instead of “functional dependency”. Actually the “determinant” is the proper name of the left hand side of a functional dependency, while the “determinate” is tha name of the rigth hand side. For instance, `description->director,serialno` is a functional dependency in which the determinant is `{description}`, and `{director, serialno}` is the determinate. The reason for this terminology is clear: the left hand side uniquely “determines” the rigth hand side.

*Keys and functional dependencies*

The information about the primary key of the three relations is redundant (non essential) with respect to the following functional dependencies. This is due to the fact that from the functional dependencies one can derive all the candidate keys of a relation (in general a relation can have more than one candidate key).

**Reformulation of the exercise**

So, to give an answer to your question, I think that we should try to reformulate the exercise as something like:

Given a relation:

```
R(name, addr, memberno, description, director, serialno, date)
```

with functional dependencies:

```
description->director,serialno
serialno->description
serialno->director
name,addr -> memberno
memberno -> name,addr
serialno,date -> memberno
```

and the decomposition in three relations:

```
customer(name,addr,memberno)
movie(description,director,serialno)
borrow(memberno,date,serialno)
```

what is the maximum possible value of x such that the relations `customer`, `movie` and `borrow` satisfy the xNF form?

**The answer**

From the given functional dependencies, we can obtain all the candidate keys of the original relation. There are two candidate keys:

```
date description
```

and

```
date serialno
```

In the schema `customer`, the following functional dependencies hold:

```
memberno -> name, addr
addr, name -> memberno
```

Since in this relation both `{memberno}` and `{addr, name}` are candidate keys, no dependency violates the BCNF, and the relation is in BCNF.

In the schema `movie`, the following functional dependencies hold:

```
serialno -> director, description
description -> serialno, director
```

and since `{serialno}` and `{description}` are both candidate keys, also this relation is in BCNF.

Finally, in the schema `borrow` the functional dependencies:

```
date, serialno -> memberno
```

holds, and since both the attributes are the only candidate key, the relation is in BCNF.

So all the three relations are in BCNF, and your initial answer, given my "re-interpretation” of the question, is correct.